# singularity and blow up for the cusp

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, singularity-theory

Take the exercise from Arnold's [book](http://libgen.rs/book/index.php?md5=531EE80BCC37E281D60AA8531A44E6FD) at page 10 where we are told to solve the singularity at $0$ of the curve $x^2=y^3$.
The solution is given by the following graphs :

[image: Arnold solution]

From the first graph, we consider the space $\mathbb{R}P^1\times \mathbb{R}$ with local coordinates $(x/y,y)$ and the curve has the following equation : $v^2=y$, hence we obtain the second graph.

But then how to obtain the third graph since we know that the image a contact of order $1$ by a blow up is a contact of order $0$. So we should have only two straight lines intersecting at $0$ ? why $3$ ?

Comment: Please respond to the answer, either by following up with more details, by asking further questions, or by accepting the answer so that this question doesn't stay on the unanswered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what's going on. Ordinarily we look at just the *proper transform* of the curve when we blow up, not the total transform. The equation in $(v,y)$-space becomes $(vy)^2=y^3$, so $y^2=0$ or $y=v^2$. The proper transform is just the parabola $y=v^2$, which is already smooth. If we are going to include $y^2=0$, then we have the parabola tangent to a *double* line. If we blow up again by setting $y=vz$, then we have $(vz)^2=0$, $v=0$, and $z=v$, so we have three lines (two double).

Can you edit your post to include more details from the text. Nor do I understand your "contact of order 1" remark. If we have a parabola and a line, it's then a double line, so we have contact order 2?